# Get count of Number of Children a row has

Tags: sql

I have a table containing a list of products, some products have a parent stored in the table and I want to show the number of children that a product has.

| ProductID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 ------ | ------NULL |
| 2------- | ------NULL |
| 3 ------ | -----------1 |
| 4 ------- | ----------1 |

Would Then Show As:

| ProductID | ParentID | CountOfChild |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 ------ | ------NULL | --------2 |
| 2------- | -----NULL | ---NULL |
| 3 ------ | ----------1 | ---NULL |
| 4 ------- | ----------1 | ----NULL |

I Tried the Statement

```
SELECT ProductID, ParentID, COUNT(ParentID)
FROM Product
GROUP BY ProundID
```

But no success I am really not sure how to go about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery.  Note that this returns `0` rather than `NULL` which seems sensible to me:

```
select p.*,
       (select count(*)
        from product p2
        where p2.parentId = p.productId
       ) as num_children
from product p;
```

Comment: I think, your solution is better in case when we need the rows with no children as well. But, tbh, it's not clear if we really need them. And, as I see, you have strong knowledge. May I ask you a question? I was always wandering: if I'm writing a subquery, is it will be executed N times, for each row, or is it optimized to be executed once, just like in case of JOIN? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @madbird . . . SQL is a *descriptive* language.  In this case, the optimizer could rewrite the subquery using appropriate `JOIN` algorithms. With the right indexes, though, this will generally be faster than alternative methods that use a `GROUP BY` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you a products that have any children:

```
SELECT ParentID, COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) FROM Product GROUP BY ParentID
```

If you need all the products (even with no children), just add the products with no children:

```
SELECT ProductID, 0 FROM Product WHERE ProductID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentID FROM Product)
UNION ALL
SELECT ParentID, COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) FROM Product GROUP BY ParentID
```